# find a $\int_{x}^{g(x)} f(t)\,dt = 1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [0, 2] → \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, positive function and  $$\int_{0}^1 f(x)\,dx = \int_{1}^2 f(x)\,dx= 1$$
For each $x \in [0, 1]$, prove that there exists a unique function $g(x) \in [1, 2]$ such that $$\int_{x}^{g(x)} f(t)\,dt = 1$$ and $g \in C^1$. Well, I think in $g(x) = x +1$, but I'm not sure. Any hint is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you know about $$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt\,?$$

Comment: thank you @DanielFischer for reply. Because f is continuous and > 0, $F'(c) = f(c) > 0$ for $c \in [0,1] \subset [0,2]$. I am trying to finish the problem with that hint given by mookid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** let $F(x) = \int_0^x f(x) dx$. $F'\ge 0$ so $F$ increases strictly, so it is a bijection.
You look for a $g(x)$ such as $F(g(x)) - F(x)= 1$, which has a unique solution:
$$
g(x) = F^{-1}(1+F(x))
$$and it proves that $g$ is $C^1$ with derivative
$$
g'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{f(F^{-1}(1+F(x)))} =  \frac{f(x)}{f\circ g(x)}
$$

Comment: Thank you @mookid for the nice hint, i am trying to connect the dots and finish the problem.

Comment: where do you use what $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx= \int_{1}^{2} f(x) dx =1$?

Comment: where do you use what $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx= \int_{1}^{2} f(x) dx =1$? also why if $F' \geq 0$ then $F$ is increases strictly, and it is a biyection??