# Find a function g such that $\int_{x}^{g(x)}f(t)dt = 1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider the question in [find a $\int_{x}^{g(x)} f(t)\,dt = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980169/find-a-int-xgx-ft-dt-1). I tried to solve it using ODE.

My attempt:
Consider
$$H(x) = \int_{x}^{g(x)}f(t)dt$$

for all $x \in [0, 1]$. We look for a $g$ such that $H(x) = 1, \forall x \in [0, 1]$

Thus

\begin{equation} \label{edo}
    H'(x) = f(g(x))\cdot g'(x) - f(x) = 0
\end{equation}

Finally, we have a separable ODE. By the exercise $g(0) = 1$. Then, we can solve the IVP.

Someone can tell if my attempt is correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, if you define "find the function" as satisfied by "give an IVP with unique solution", then this is correct. But also the accepted answer in the original question directly gives a formula for $g(x)$ via the inverse of the anti-derivative of $F$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann As we are using a separable ODE we can also find an explicit solution for g.

Comment: Yes, and that explicit solution is given in the answer of the original, linked question.